# Should I delete my question or keep it?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, deleted-questions

Not finding a solution, I posted [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/243092/19937) but now see it is covered by [this one with an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/179150/19937).

Should I just delete it, or is it better to close as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up on meta so quickly. As already remarked by [@Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin) in the comments:

> We can keep it & link it as a duplicate - which gives Google a greater chance of finding the answer in future. I'll vote to close as a dupe; it doesn't reflect on the quality of the question, merely links it to an existing one with a highly-voted answer.

Comment: @Sergei believes it is not a dup and they can answer it, I've asked them to explain so we can reopen.